# How to compute the pair wise addition of two tables of tensors in torch

Tags: lua, torch

I have two layers in my network(deep neural network) L1 and L2 which outputs tables of tensors. Suppose output is table T1 and T2 of size m and n(it means T1 & T2 have m and n tensors respectively).

Now I want the addition of each pair of tensors of T1 and T2 so that resulting table has $m \times n$ tensors of same size.

How to do it in torch ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, just use `nn.CAddTable` class.

```
require 'nn'

T1 = torch.Tensor(20,10)
T2 = torch.Tensor(20,10)

m = nn.CAddTable()
m:forward({T1,T2})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but CAddTable add corresponding tensors... I want addition of each tensor in T1 with each tensor in T2.

Comment: It is not very clear from your question. Please give more details on your tensor structures.